# amp error while applying the [hide] and [show] TOC button

Tags: javascript, onclick, amp-html

I am facing these errors while checking with the amp validator, can anybody help me to add [hide] and [show] TOC button in my TOC

Custom JavaScript is not allowed.
line 4, column 0

Custom JavaScript is not allowed.
line 29, column 0

Invalid URL protocol 'javascript:' for attribute 'href' in tag 'a'.
line 784, column 10

The attribute 'onclick' may not appear in tag 'a'.
line 784, column 10

Invalid URL protocol 'javascript:' for attribute 'href' in tag 'a'.
line 784, column 87

The attribute 'onclick' may not appear in tag 'a'.
line 784, column 87
[the link with amp validator dubug](https://www.agritechknowledge.com/2020/07/secrets-of-goat-farming-in-india.html)
https://www.agritechknowledge.com/2020/07/secrets-of-goat-farming-in-india.html

Answer (score 0):

basically your using custom javascript with  element.

Remove all the custom javascript code and it should work fine.

To debug more on the same you can use at the end of the URL

```
#development=1
```

Eg:

```
https://www.agritechknowledge.com/2020/07/secrets-of-goat-farming-in-india.html/#development=1
```

And make sure you have downloaded the chrome plugin. You will get various of the options to validate in the following URL

```
https://validator.ampproject.org/
```